# Creating an array of classes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, static

Is it possible to create an array of static classes in Java?
For example:

```
SceneObject[] scenes = {Loading.class, Menu.class};
// Loading and Menu extend SceneObject
```

We need to call static methods via the array, not instantiate them.

EDIT:

The following is what we are trying to accomplish. We could alternatively use many switches, but it sounds redundant to add every object to every switch in every method.

```
package net.bitworm.gameengine;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;

import net.bitworm.scenes.*;

public class SceneController {

public enum Scene{
    LOADING_SCENE,
    MENU,
    SCENE_1
}

public static SceneObject[] scenes = {new Loading(), new Menu()};

public volatile static Scene currentScene = Scene.LOADING_SCENE;

public static void setScene(Scene newScene){
    currentScene = newScene;
    System.out.println("Switched to " + currentScene.toString());
}

public static void update(GameContainer container, int delta){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].update(container, delta);
}
public static void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].render(container, g);
}
public static void mouseMoved(int oldx, int oldy, int newx, int newy){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].mouseMoved(oldx, oldy, newx, newy);
}
public static void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].mousePressed(button, x, y);;
}
public static void mouseReleased(int button, int x, int y){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].mouseReleased(button, x, y);
}
public static void mouseWheelMoved(int change){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].mouseWheelMoved(change);
}
public static void keyPressed(int key, char c){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].keyPressed(key, c);
}
public static void keyReleased(int key, char c){
    scenes[currentScene.ordinal()].keyReleased(key, c);
}
```

Comment: Did you get an error when you tried this?

Comment: Yes. Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Menu> to SceneObject

Comment: Right, so you can define `Class[] scenes = ...`

Comment: In future, always specify an error in the question. Additionally, give more context - we can't tell what you're trying to achieve, which makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to differentiate between *classes* and *objects*. For example, you might have:

```
SceneObject[] scenes = { new Loading(), new Menu() };
```

or

```
Class[] classes = { Loading.class, Menu.class };
```

It's not clear from your question which you mean, but hopefully that should satisfy either case... note that you can't have generic arrays, so with the `Class[]` you can't specify that each class must extend `SceneObject`.

EDIT: Now we've got a bit more information, it sounds like you've got this:

```
abstract class SceneObject {}

class Menu extends SceneObject {
    static void foo() {
    }

    static void bar() {
    }
}

class Loading extends SceneObject {
    static void foo() {
    }

    static void bar() {
    }
}
```

The two `foo` methods here are completely unrelated - you can't use polymorphism to call them, because they're *static* methods. If you want to use polymorphism - i.e. call a method knowing which signature you want to call, but with an implementation that depends on the target of the call - you need *instance* methods:

```
abstract class SceneObject {
    abstract void foo() {
    }

    abstract void foo() {
    }
}

class Menu extends SceneObject {
    @Override void foo() {
    }

    @Override void bar() {
    }
}

class Loading extends SceneObject {
    @Override void foo() {
    }

    @Override void bar() {
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
SceneObject[] scenes = { new Loading(), new Menu() };

...

for (SceneObject scene : scenes) {
    scene.foo();
    scene.bar();
}
```

Comment: Cannot create a generic array of Class<? extends SceneObject>

Comment: Yep. that works, unfortunatley, when we try to call the methods from the array, the methods are undefined for type Class.

Comment: @RayToal: Well not really - you could have a `List<Class<? extends SceneObject>>` easily enough. It's just that arrays can't be generic.

Comment: Is it possible to create an array to call static methods from without instantiating any classes or using a switch?

Comment: @GraysonPike: What methods are you trying to call? If you're trying to call static methods declared on `SceneObject`, you simply can't do that with `Class` - not without using reflection. It sounds like you're trying to use inheritance for static methods, which simply doesn't work. (You can't override static methods anyway.) This goes back to my comment on your question - the more context we have, the more we can help you.

Comment: @GraysonPike: No. Fundamentally static methods aren't polymorphic, and you shouldn't try to fake polymorphism. (Creating instances in order to call *static* methods isn't a good idea either, but it sounds like you should have *instance* methods.)

Comment: We have an abstract class called SceneObject, which contains no methods. We have classes which extend the SceneObject which contain their own static methods to be called. We're only using SceneObject to create an array to hold the classes which extend it.

Comment: @GraysonPike: So actually the classes don't have anything in common, other than that they all extend a class with no specific methods? It's unclear how you can use polymorphism at all here. If the classes all have the *same* static methods, I suggest you turn them into *instance* methods and declare them as abstract methods in `SceneObject`. Then you can create an array of *instances* of the subclasses, and call the methods polymorphically.

Comment: And if all the methods of the different objects are _completely different_, then how are you calling them as you traverse the array? Reflection?

Comment: Is there any way to do this without instantiating these classes? Also the methods of the different objects are all the same.

Comment: @GraysonPike: Not if you don't want to use reflection and don't want to just hard-code the calls, no. As I *keep* saying, you're trying to mix static methods and polymorphism, and you can't do that.

Comment: Is there any alternative to using switches in this case? How would we implement reflection?

Comment: @GraysonPike Just a thought but maybe you could the singleton pattern and then you would have your instance methods. Are you trying to use static methods and not instantiate because there is only one of each kind of scene object?

Comment: @GraysonPike: Why are you so against creating instances? It's not like you need to create *lots* of instances of these. Don't fight against the language.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess instances would be best in this case. Thanks for the help and apologies for the ambiguous and contextually poor answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other than making an array of classes that extend SceneObject, we can make a container for these objects:

```
//a container that holds only the classes of SceneObject
public class ClassBox<T extends SceneObject> {
    private Class<T> theClass;

    public ClassBox(Class<T> theClass) {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
    public Class getTheClass() { //'getClass()' method is reserved, we use a more unique name
        return theClass;
    }
}

//testing classes
abstract class SceneObject {}
class Loading extends SceneObject {}
class Menu extends SceneObject {}
class noExtends1 {}

//testing 
public void main() {
    ClassBox[] scenes = {new ClassBox<>(Loading.class), new ClassBox<>(Menu.class)}; //these classes extend SceneObject
//  ClassBox[] sceneserror = {new ClassBox<>(Loading.class), new ClassBox<>(noExtends1.class)}; //gives error because 2nd array elem is not extending, so I commented it

    Log.v("custom log.v call", String.valueOf(Loading.class));
    Log.v("custom log.v call", String.valueOf(Menu.class));
    Log.v("custom log.v call", String.valueOf(scenes[0].getTheClass()));
    Log.v("custom log.v call", String.valueOf(scenes[1].getTheClass()));

//result is:
//V/custom log.v call: class me2.iwanttobealeader.pie$Loading
//V/custom log.v call: class me2.iwanttobealeader.pie$Menu
//V/custom log.v call: class me2.iwanttobealeader.pie$Loading
//V/custom log.v call: class me2.iwanttobealeader.pie$Menu
}
```

This answer has the benefit of specifying multiple criteria of inheritance for example:

```
public class ClassBox<T extends Fragment & FR_DbRequests.SynchListener>
//now it must implement the abstract class SyncListener and extend Fragment
```

But also the disadvantage of instantiating an additional object ,namely the container+variable containing the class, instead of just the variable containing the class.

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Comment: Actually it's not "the one", it's just another way of making an array of classes, but let me just edit the answer.